# Einstein really didn't "accept" quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, theoretical-physics, einstein

It is sometimes said that Einstein didn't accept quantum mechanics. Some stronger claims are that he viewed it as wrong altogether, considering it not a viable description of nature.

Well, I want to know the historical truth about this. Did Einstein really despise quantum mechanics to the point of dequalifying it as a correct theory of nature?

Or he simply didn't agree to the interpretations people gave to it? Or even he just considered it to be "right, but not the end", so that he believed one day something more fundamental could be found giving a better explanation to it?

I might be wrong, but I think Einstein didn't really totally viewed quantum mechanics as wrong, after all if I'm not mistaken (and I can certainly be), he was one of the first to work with something related to entanglment (the so-called EPR paradox).

Comment: Entire books have been written on this, e.g. A. D. Stone’s recent [Einstein and the Quantum](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/10068.html).

Comment: My personal take on this is that he didn't agree with the loss of determinism and locality; this was the key principle that he was investigating with the EPR paradox.

Comment: See e.g. [Bohr–Einstein debates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Einstein_debates).

Answer (score 2):

Einstein's objections to QM are best understood by his famous EPR paper written in 1936.  Einstein proposed a thought experiment to determine whether QM was local and real.  The locality part is that no signal of information can travel faster than the speed of light.  The "Reality" part is that nature (let's say an assemblage of particles) is real even when it is not being observed.

Einstein's proposition is that the current QM theories could not be both real and local unless other hidden variables were added to the theory.  So, this was then known as the issue of QM Completeness -- that is, QM is not complete.

The reality requirement of Einstein was directed primarily against the Copenhagen Interpretation where Bohr claims that momentum (for example) does not exist as a measurable quantity if it is not being observed.  Or observation causes momentum of a particle to exist.

I admit that in the above I am glossing over the more subtle arguments in the issue.  However, an excellent book on this very topic that covers all of the sides of Einstein's angst and arguments is [What is Real?  The Unfinished Quest for the Meaning of Quantum Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465096050).

Answer (score 2):

I don't  think    Einstein  completely  rejected   quantum  Mechanics,  but  he did  disagree  with  other  people's   interpretations     and  opinions.  He   said  "God  does  not  play   dice  with  the universe." At  the  subatomic  and  quark  scales  of  size,  God  DOES  play    dice   with  the  Universe.  Let's  not  get  diverted  into  whether  God  exists  or  not.

I'd  have  to  look  up   if  he  said  anything  about   about  or  Heisenberg  about  the  Heisenberg  uncertainty   principle,  basically  that  just  by  observing    and  trying  to  measure   something   you  disturb  t  and   change   the  system   assuming  the   system  is  a closed  system,.  LOTS  of  people  disagree   about  whether  the  Universe  is  completely "closed"  system  or  no,   Often   that  is  based  in their  own ignorance.

Einstein   was  just  one   of many  people  who   shattered  the  classical  Newtonian    "model"   of a clockwork   Universe.  Disagreement  and  peer  review   is  part  of   of  the  scientific  method,   which   basically  is     a logical  objective   guessing   game   with   flashes  of  serendipity   and  inspiration.   it  took  me  about  15  to  20  minutes   for my  master's  thesis   to  admit   that   and  to   agree   that   usually  most  scientists  will NOT  admit  to  that   because   peer  pressure      and  the  risk  of  damaging  their  won  credibility   with  the  general  public,   and  he  may  have  been   thinking    their  students.   i  was  his  last  graduate   student.    and   retirement   and  becoming   an  Emeritus  professor was less   than   3  years   in  the  future  for  him.  of  course  this   conversation   was  late  Friday   afternoon   conversation   as   well  that  went  on  past  5  pm.

Objective, logical, analytical, critical and unbiased thinking is NOT  "normal"    Way  to think   for   anyone,  Including  people  who  think  deductively   rather    inductively.    We   each have  our  own  unique  perspective  of  the  universe.  We  each live  in  out  own  subjective  universes.  "Truth"  is   subjective  is  too.  What  may   be   'true'   for  you,  may   be   fatal   for  me..  Survival  of  the  fittest   is   what   it  is  all  about.

I don't  think  Einstein   rejected  all  of  quantum  mechanics. He  wasn't  that  closed  minded    completely    stuck  in   the  paradigm  that  he  had    shattered   along  with other  people.   As  someone  else  has  already  said,  entire  books   have  been  written  about  this.